# Set up Dependency Injection on Service Fabric using default ASP.NET Core DI container

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I would like to use ASP.NET Core's default DI container to setup DI for my Service Fabric project.

```
//This is what I've got so far, and it works great
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync(
  "MyServiceType",
  context => new MyService(context, new MyMonitor()
).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

//This is how I use it
public MyService(StatefulServiceContext context, IMonitor myMonitor)
  : base(context)
{
  this._myMonitor = myMonitor;           
}
```

How would I set up DI, if `MyMonitor` class has a dependency on a `ConfigProvider` class, like this:

```
public MyMonitor(IConfigProvider configProvider)
{
  this._configProvider = configProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this question will give you some light: [Why does ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync return before the serviceFactory func completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759837/why-does-serviceruntime-registerserviceasync-return-before-the-servicefactory-fu/53761067#53761067)

Technically, the `ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync()` is a dependency registration, it requires you to pass the serviceTypeName and the factory method responsible for creating the services `Func<StatelessServiceContext, StatelessService> serviceFactory`

The factory method receives the context and returns a service (Stateful or stateless).

For DI, you should register all dependencies in advance and call resolve services to create the constructor, something like:

```
var provider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddSingleton<IFooService, FooService>()
            .AddSingleton<IMonitor, MyMonitor>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("MyServiceType",
    context => new MyService(context, provider.GetService<IMonitor>());
}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

PS:

> - Never Register the context (StatelessServiceContext\StatefulServiceContext) in the DI, in a shared process approach, multiple partitions might be hosted on same process and will have multiple contexts.
> - This code snippet is **not tested**, I've used in the past, don't have access to validate if matches the same code, but is very close to the approach used, might need some tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @OscarCabreraRodríguez

I am working on the project that simplifies development of Service Fabric Reliable Services and it has great built-in support for dependency injection scenarios.

You can find general information [project page](https://github.com/coherentsolutionsinc/aspnetcore-service-fabric-hosting), [wiki](https://github.com/coherentsolutionsinc/aspnetcore-service-fabric-hosting/wiki) and specific information about dependency injection [here](https://github.com/coherentsolutionsinc/aspnetcore-service-fabric-hosting/wiki/understanding-dependency-injection).

The idea is that project abstracts you from working with `Service` instance directly instead providing you with a set of more concrete objects.

Here is a simple example for ASP.NET Core application:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  new HostBuilder()
    .DefineStatefulService(
      serviceBuilder =>
      {
        serviceBuilder
          .UseServiceType("ServiceType")
          .DefineAspNetCoreListener(
            listenerBuilder =>
            {
              listenerBuilder
                .UseEndpoint("ServiceEndpoint")
                .UseUniqueServiceUrlIntegration()
                .ConfigureWebHost(
                  webHostBuilder => 
                  { 
                    webHostBuilder
                      .ConfigureServices(
                        services =>
                        {
                          // You can configure as usual.
                          services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
                        })
                      .UseStartup<Startup>(); 
                  });
            });
      })
      .Build()
      .Run();

[Route("api")]
public class ApiController : Controller
{
  public ApiController(IMyService service) { }

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("value")]
  public string GetValue()
  {
    return $"Value from {nameof(ApiController)}";
  }
}
```

Hope I understand your use case correctly and this information is relevant.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg Karasik, but I preferred to use the answer by Diego Mendes(below), because it was closer to what I was looking for