# Register IReliableStateManagerReplica using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have Stateful Service fabric service which has the below constructor.

```
public StatefuleService(StatefulServiceContext context, IReliableStateManagerReplica manager,
IActorProxyFactory actorProxyFactory = null)
            : base(context, manager)
        {
            ActorProxyFactory = actorProxyFactory ?? new ActorProxyFactory();
        }
```

I'm using Autofac to register the components. How can I register IReliableStateManagerReplica using Autofac? 
I tried

```
builder.RegisterType<ReliableStateManager>().As<IReliableStateManagerReplica>().SingleInstance;
```

but it gives the following exception:

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.ReliableStateManager' can be invoked
>   with the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter
>   'System.Fabric.StatefulServiceContext serviceContext' of constructor
>   'Void .ctor(System.Fabric.StatefulServiceContext,
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.ReliableStateManagerConfiguration)'.

Comment: Can you post the resolve code?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the constructor `StatefulService(StatefulServiceContext, IReliableStateManagerReplica)` is to initialize a new instance of the ***StatefulService*** class with non-default reliable state manager replica.

This means, that you have implemented your own version of reliable state provider with a custom logic and does not want to use the default implemented by Service Fabric.

If this is not the case, you should use the default constructor `StatefulService(StatefulServiceContext)` and if you need access to the StateManager, you can access it from `((StatefulServiceContext)context).StateManager`

Another recommendation I give to you, you should not create StatefulService using the DI, because the ***StatefulServiceContext*** is created at runtime and multiple replicas\partitions can reuse the same process in a shared host, that means you may have multiple StatefulServiceContext and the DI does not know which one to use.

Please take a look on this other SO:
[Set up Dependency Injection on Service Fabric using default ASP.NET Core DI container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185571/set-up-dependency-injection-on-service-fabric-using-default-asp-net-core-di-cont/54199092)

Comment: Hi, appreciate your recommendation. But if I want to use my custom constructor instead of the default one, how do I register IReliableStateManagerReplica using Autofac? Can it be done?